# intellisense and code complete for DefinitelyTyped (TypeScript type definitions) on WebStorm IDE

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

How can I get WebStorm IDE to give me code completion for libraries that I've downloaded.

[image: JavaScript Libraries]

As you can see `angularjs-DefinitelyTyped` and `jQuery-DefinitelyTyped` have been downloaded.

Now I believe that I have to reference the definition file in my .ts files.

[image: Code]

But, where WebStorm saves the definition files so I can reference them in my code?

Thank you!

Comment: I find that if you include all of the necessary files, everything just works. I use Ext JS and I haven't ever needed to use the WebStorm Libraries functionality.

Comment: I just find it weird with there is an option in the IDE to download the reference files, set their scope to Global and then what? :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That dialog is for *JavaScript* scope, not *TypeScript* scope (e.g. see mocha demo http://youtu.be/4mKiGkokyx8?t=1m19s). That is, Webstorm is using TypeScript definitions to give intellisence for JavaScript.

For TypeScript itself you need to include the definitions into your project manually (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts) and reference them like you always have.

Answer (score 21):

As basarat says in his answer, you need to include the definitions manually. The easiest way to do this is with [tsd](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd). Once installed (`npm install -g tsd`), navigate to the directory you want to hold the typings, and install definition files (such as angular, in the following example) like this:

```
tsd query angular --action install
```

or, better yet:

```
tsd init
tsd query angular --save --action install
```

Note that you can do all this within Webstorm (alt-F12 opens a terminal window).

Answer (score 0):

On Webstorm for mac

```
Preferences->Languages&Frameworks->Typescript
```

Use tsconfig.json should be checked
and you should create a tsconfig.json file which contains

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```