# External Libraries vs. "<reference path=" for TypeScript in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I am trying to understand how to get WebStorm 9 to recognize external TypeScript libraries.  I tried to add "TypeScript Community Stubs" for an external library -- for example knockout -- and that results in an Application Library called knockout-DefinitelyTypes to appear in my "External Libraries" node in the project tree.  Expanding that node shows /Users/Decker/Library/Caches/WebStorm9/extLibs/http_github.com_borisyankov_DefinitelyTyped_raw_master_knockout_knockout.d.ts.  My expectation is that that would allow me, in my own typescript file, to create a line like:

```
var name = ko.observable('Hi');
```

But the TypeScript will not compile and gives the error "Cannot find name 'ko'".  I am able to solve this by downloading the TypeScript definition file manually (from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) and storing it in my project -- in my case at /scripts/typings/knockout.d.ts -- and then reference it with this line in my TypeScript source file:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/knockout.d.ts" />
```

I thought that WebStorm's external library would alleviate the need for the  tag.  Indeed, I'm not sure what it accomplished for me as I had to download and reference the definition file manually.  Am I misunderstanding something?  TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Indeed, I'm not sure what it accomplished for me as I had to download and reference the definition file manually. Am I misunderstanding something

The stubs that webstorm downloads are only for JS. For TS you need to download and reference manually : [intellisense and code complete for DefinitelyTyped (TypeScript type definitions) on WebStorm IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367328/intellisense-and-code-complete-for-definitelytyped-typescript-type-definitions)

Comment: Would you know how to the opposite? Make WebStorm use `typings` in package.json or an actual d.ts file from the package to provide autocompletion support and hinting for JS code? I have a library written in TS, compiled and published on npm. In my project I want to use my own d.ts which is not on DefintelyTyped repo.