# How to use @implements

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

I have a `Model` class (in nodejs) and I want to implement it from `AuthorizationCodeModel`.

I want WebStorm detect that my model implemented the interface and suggest me auto complete

[Interface](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/oauth2-server/index.d.ts#L232).

Model:

```
  /**
   * @implements AuthorizationCodeModel
   */
  class Model {
  }
```

the `@implements AuthorizationCodeModel` is not working. How can I use JSDoc?

Answer (score 0):

example interface in typescript

```
interface ClockInterface {
    currentTime: Date;
}

class Clock implements ClockInterface {
    currentTime: Date;
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

[What's the difference between 'extends' and 'implements' in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834625/whats-the-difference-between-extends-and-implements-in-typescript)

JSDOC examples: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-implements.html

---

If autocomplete in Webstorm not worked, try to set `reference path in js file`

```
/// <reference path="components/someClass.js"/>
/// <reference path="components/someInterface.js"/>
/// <reference path="components/AuthorizationCodeModel.js"/>

/**
* @implements AuthorizationCodeModel
*/
class Model { }
```

`Reference paths` also use for autocomplete in some popular IDEs

https://madskristensen.net/blog/the-story-behind-_referencesjs

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206352279-How-to-not-reference-other-js-files

[intellisense and code complete for DefinitelyTyped (TypeScript type definitions) on WebStorm IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367328/intellisense-and-code-complete-for-definitelytyped-typescript-type-definitions)

Comment: I don't use typescript , My code is a nodejs code and the type script code is a stub created by DefinitelyTyped

Comment: As I mentioned @implements AuthorizationCodeModel is not worked , WebStorm dont suggest me auto complete

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone ends up here for an "`interface`" that they implement that they're trying to import, it turns out if you're exporting an `interface` from one module, you must use a `class` statement; not a `class` expression.

If you're trying to use an imported interface like this:

```js
const { MyInterface } = require('./interfaceFile');

/**
 * @implements MyInterface
 */
class MyImplementation {

}
```

Will not work:

```js
/**
 * @interface
 */
module.exports.MyInterface = class MyInterface {
   . . .
}
```

Will work:

```js
/**
 * @interface
 */
class MyInterface {
   . . .
}

module.exports.MyInterface = MyInterface;
```

Not 100% the original issue, but I can see people who are having my issue also ending up here.